# Proving and supplying counterexamples for few basic facts regarding open and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

$\newcommand{\absval}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$
I spent a considerable amount of time ($>2$ hours) thinking about the below questions, however my arguments are sloppy. Could you give me some hints on how to proceed with (b),(c) and (d)?

> Decide whether the following statements are true or false. Provide counterexamples for those that are false, and supply proofs for those that are true.

> (a) An open set that contains every rational number must necessarily be all of $\mathbf{R}$.

> (b) The Nested Interval property remains true if the term "closed interval" is replaced by "closed set".

> (c) Every nonempty open set contains a rational number.

> (d) Every bounded infinite closed set contains a rational number.

> (e) The Cantor Set is closed.

***My Attempt.***

(a) I think that this proposition is true. We proceed by contradiction. Let $O \supseteq \mathbf{Q}$ be an open set containing all the rationals. Assume that this is not the whole of $\mathbf{R}$. Then, $\exists x \in O^C \cap \mathbf{R}$. Since $O^C$ is a closed set, there exists a sequence of rational numbers $(q_n) \in O^C$, such that $\lim q_n = x$, with $q_n \ne x$ for all $n \in\mathbf{N}$. But, this implies $O \not\supseteq Q$. This leads to a contradiction. Hence, our initial assumption is false.

(b) I could not think of counterexamples here. For instance, consider the decreasing sequence of closed sets
\begin{align*}
    A_n = \left\{-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right\}
\end{align*}

We have $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 \ldots$ and $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \{0\} \ne \emptyset$.

Another example could be,
\begin{align*}
    A_n = \left\{-1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right\}
\end{align*}

(c) Let $O$ be a non-empty open set and say, $x \in O$. Then, there exists an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood $V_\epsilon(x)$ such that $V_\epsilon(x) \subseteq O$. Since, $(x-\epsilon,x] \subseteq O$, and the set of real numbers $\mathbf{R}$ are dense in $\mathbf{Q}$, there exists a rational number $m/n$ between the two reals $x - \epsilon < \frac{m}{n} < x$. So, every non-empty open set $O$ contains a rational number.

(d) Consider the bounded infinite closed sets
\begin{align*}
    A_n = \left\{1 + \frac{1}{n}:n \in \mathbf{N}\right\} \cup \{1\}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    B_n = \left\{\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2})^{2n-1}}:n \in \mathbf{N}\right\} \cup \{0\}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    C_n = \left\{x_n: x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x_n + \frac{2}{x_n}, x_1 = 1\right)\right\} \cup \{\sqrt{2}\}
\end{align*}

$A_n, B_n, C_n$ contain rational numbers. I couldn't think of a counterexample here.

By AoC, every bounded infinite closed subset of $\mathbf{R}$ has a least upper bound. Let $s = \sup A$. Since, $A$ is closed, $s \in A$. We have a dichotomy: either (i) the supremum is irrational or (ii) the supremum is rational number. If $s$ is rational, then we are done. If $s$ is irrational and then there exists a sequence of rationals in $A$, such that $\absval{q - s} < \epsilon$.

(e) The Cantor set is the limit set formed by recursively removing the open middle one-thirds. So, \begin{align*}
    C = [0,1] - \left[\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right) \cup \left(\frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9}\right) \cup \left(\frac{7}{9},\frac{8}{9}\right) \ldots \right]
\end{align*}

The countable union of open sets is open. Since $C$ is the complement of an open set, it is closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a) This is false: $\Bbb R\setminus\left\{\pi\right\}\ne\Bbb R$.

(b) It is also false: $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[n,\infty)=\emptyset$.

(c) True, since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. Indeed, that's what “dense” means.

(d) It is false. Take, say, $\displaystyle\{\pi\}\cup\left\{\pi+\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$.

(e) Your answer is correct.

Comment: Wow! How do I get better at thinking counterexamples or writing proofs.. :)

Comment: Well, that's independent from this question, right?!

Comment: Sure, I didn't mean to digress and go off topic. It's a soft question for another time. I'll focus and practice.

Comment: @Quasar you get better at subject X by (eh but not only by i guess) studying subject X+1. i think even a million exercises on subject X will not help you get that much better at subject X. idk.

Comment: @BCLC, please illuminate me a bit more. I'm willing to put in the leg-work. Do you mean, learning another area such as probability th, & getting a broader understanding?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, for (a) $\mathbb{R} - \{\sqrt{2}\} \ne \mathbb{R}$ and (d) $\sqrt{2} + \{\sqrt{2} + 1/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ are also valid counterexamples,right?

Comment: @Quasar Yes, they are. In fact, you can use *any* irrational number instead of $\pi$ in both cases.

Comment: @Quasar not really another area. the 'next' subject. i think these kinds of questions are less difficult when you study elementary topology. i just mean who cares about 'How do I get better at thinking counterexamples or writing proofs' right now when asking on stackexchange is just good enough and then eventually you just will get better. i don't think anyone really needs to 'get better' at this point.